# How to show full list of build history for a Hudson project?

Tags: hudson

Using Hudson v1.396 hosted on Linux, and looking at the project's home page with Firefox on Windows7, there is a pane on the lower left titled "Build History" that shows the last twenty builds for the project. How do I see earlier history?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the project's configuration - specifically the **Discard Old Builds** setting. If it is set, then you will be limited to how many builds you are keeping. If it is not set, then you should see a "more..." link at the bottom of the list, as well as an RSS link for a full feed of the builds.

Comment: That tells me how to extend the window of past builds I keep before they roll off, but I don't need the bits, just the build history data. Is the data about the old builds irretrievably lost when the build archive retention times-out?